# Why can't the C# compiler tell that this function always returns or throws?

Tags: c#, exception, for-loop, code-analysis

I have the following (simplified) method:

```
public bool DoWorkWithRetry()
{
    for (int remainingTries = Constants.MaxRetries; remainingTries >= 0; remainingTries--)
    {
        try
        {
            return DoWork();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (remainingTries == 0)
            {
                throw new WorkException(
                        String.Format("Failed after {0} retries.", Constants.MaxRetries),
                        ex);
            }
            // fall through to retry
        }
    }
}
```

It seems pretty clear to me that this method either *returns* or *throws*. However, the C# compiler complains at me that `not all code paths return a value`.

- Is this a limitation of the C# compiler's code-analysis?
- Or is there some condition that I'm not seeing where the `for` loop could complete without either throwing or returning?

Comment: Are you sure to reuse the exception object? What if the reason for the exception is not always the same? Alternatively, remember all exceptions thrown and pass them up as a group.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The compiler is just following the language specification.

The language does *not* try to perform analysis of "if you start with an integer and subtract one repeatedly, you will always end up hitting zero at some point". That's even assuming that `Constants.MaxRetries` is a compile-time constant.

Basically, the language specification has rules for *reachability* - and the end point of a `for` statement is reachable if *either* of these is true (section 8.8.3 of the C# 4 spec):

- The `for` statement contains a reachable `break` statement that exits the `for` statement
- The `for` statement is reachable and a *for-condition* is present and does not have the constant value`true`

The latter point is the case here, so the end of the `for` statement is reachable. The end of a non-void method is not allowed to be reachable, hence the error. (Section 8.1 of the C# spec.)

The alternative is to make the language *much, much* more complicated. I'm perfectly okay with this not compiling.

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't know that the for loop will always execute at least once.  It considers it a valid option that it never runs at all, in which case it doesn't `throw` or `return`.

While through sufficently complex analysis of your program it's theoretically possible to prove that it always does return or throw, such analysis is very complex and performance intensive.  The C# compiler team didn't want to take the risk of mistakes, or consider the substantially increased time of compiling in order to add this complex analysis.  They chose to use a simpler definition of "reachable" vs "unreachable" code that is both easier and faster to implement.

As for an actual fix, just add a `throw` at the very end of the method, and possibly put in a comment stating that it's not actually possible to hit it.

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't the C# compiler tell that this function always returns or throws?

The compiler doesn't try to simulate how your program works to see which branches can be executed. It just looks at all the possible branches. In your case if for some reason `remainingTries >= 0` evaluated to false then it would fall off the end of your method without returning a boolean or throwing.

You can fix it by removing the check in the `for` loop:

```
public bool DoWorkWithRetry()
{
    for (int remainingTries = Constants.MaxRetries;; remainingTries--)
    {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

That check has no useful purpose anyway.

You could also rewrite your method to totally avoid the problem:

```
for (int remainingTries = Constants.MaxRetries; remainingTries >= 0; remainingTries--)
{
    try
    {
        return DoWork();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // fall through to retry
    }
}

throw new WorkException(
        String.Format("Failed after {0} retries.", Constants.MaxRetries),
        ex);
```

Also please don't catch and swallow all exceptions. Catch specific exceptions that you know about. Catching all possible exceptions is a bad idea.

Comment: And how exactly is `remainingTries` supposed to get below 0?

Comment: @JSBձոգչ The compiler doesn't do that sort of navel gazing.

Comment: No, if remainingtries falls below zero, the code in the catch block throws a different exception.

Comment: @Wug: The compiler doesn't evaluate that either.  Exceptions are *runtime* occurrences, not compile-time ones.

Answer (score 2):

Does the compiler still complain if you refactor it to this equivalent code?

```
public bool DoWorkWithRetry()
{
    Exception e;
    for (int remainingTries = Constants.MaxRetries; remainingTries >= 0; remainingTries--)
    {
        try
        {
            return DoWork();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            e = ex;
        }
    }
    throw new WorkException(
         String.Format("Failed after {0} retries.", Constants.MaxRetries), e);
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain about that, and in fact, this is what I wrote as a workaround. But I was curious as to why the compiler makes this mistake in the first place.

Comment: @JSBձոգչ It's not a *mistake*.  They choose not to implement this feature.

Comment: I was about to post the exact same, except I would not have re-used the Exception object (i.e. what if it fails for different reasons each time)

Comment: @phresnel: I wondered about that too, but this way it does exactly what it originally did, which is reuse only the last thrown exception.

Comment: @Wug: True, you followed the refactoring scheme "one at a time" :)

Answer (score 0):

It would have to be too smart to know whether what is in the for loop ever gets executed at all. For it to know, it would have to test that the for loop is actually getting executed because the `MaxRitries >= 0`.